# IONOS subdominios Angular reload

Tags: angular, .htaccess, hosting

tengo un problema con el hosting IONOS y Angular.
Subo el proyecto al servidor y todo funciona correctamente menos los reloads que petan con un 404. Al añadir el .htaccess me dan los siguientes errores:

**app.corsind.com/:19 GET https://app.corsind.com/polyfills.bf99d438b005d57b2b31.js net::ERR_ABORTED 500
app.corsind.com/:13 GET https://app.corsind.com/styles.6f71438dd8da78625119.css net::ERR_ABORTED 500
app.corsind.com/:20 GET https://app.corsind.com/main.0f70a54781d65c3715d3.js net::ERR_ABORTED 500
app.corsind.com/:18 GET https://app.corsind.com/runtime.ed9d973e507d2f11f57e.js net::ERR_ABORTED 500
app.corsind.com/:19 GET https://app.corsind.com/polyfills.bf99d438b005d57b2b31.js net::ERR_ABORTED 500
app.corsind.com/:20 GET https://app.corsind.com/main.0f70a54781d65c3715d3.js net::ERR_ABORTED 500
favicon.ico:1 GET https://app.corsind.com/favicon.ico 500**

Por lo que entiendo que tengo un problema en el htaccess... Os lo adjunto aquí:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # -- REDIRECTION to https (optional):
    # If you need this, uncomment the next two commands
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
    # --
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) index.html [NC,L]
</IfModule>
#------------ BROWSER CACHING (optional)
# Disable browser caching for all files that don't get a hash string by Angular.
<FilesMatch "^(?!.*\.([0-9a-z]{20})\.).*$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    FileETag None
    Header unset ETag
    Header unset Pragma
    Header unset Cache-Control
    Header unset Last-Modified
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Expires "Mon, 10 Apr 1972 00:00:00 GMT"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
#------------
```

Lo raro es que si en el htaccess comento alguna de las dos lineas de RewriteRule después de la condición todo funciona menos el reload... así que estoy como al principio.

Alguién ha trabajado angular en Ionos o sabe como ayudarme?

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Estoy en la misma situación y no sé qué hacer.
He probado lo siguiente, sin éxito:

[Generador automático de .htaccess](https://julianpoemp.github.io/ngx-htaccess-generator/#/generator)

[Tutorial para las últimas versiones](https://codeon.hashnode.dev/how-to-deploy-angular-app-on-shared-hosting-cka9i0wbb00n1c5s1xvm6pyq1)

Pensé que quizás fuese problema de mi aplicación, por lo que creé una nueva de prueba con routing entre dos componentes vacíos, pero obtuve el mismo resultado.

¿Lograste solucionarlo?

Comment: Esto en realidad no responde a la pregunta, [si tienes otra pregunta puedes formularla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), añade como referencia esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto, si tienes dudas puedes consultar el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help). Saludos

Comment: Hola, perdona soy nuevo aquí. ¿Qué debo hacer en casos como este, en el que la pregunta no fue respondida en dos meses y quiero saber si quien preguntó obtuvo la respuesta por sí mismo/a? ¿Volver a reformularla? ¿No sería eso repetir la misma pregunta y sería malo para el foro al haber duplicados? Un saludo.

Comment: Si vas al perfil te das cuenta de su última conexión, en este caso la cuenta y la pregunta están abandonadas, lo más viable es volver a formular la pregunta y en este caso no pueden cerrar tu pregunta por duplicados porque la primera no tiene respuestas, este tipo de preguntas sin respuestas en bastante tiempo son borradas por procesos del sitio